# Проблема с шрифтом в Qt

Tags: python, windows, qml, pyside, шрифты

Имеется:

- QtCreator
- Windows 7
- установленный в системе шрифт BarnaulGrotesk

Что получается? А получается, что в самописной программе на QML + Python (PySide) вместо этого шрифта для кириллицы используется стандартный шрифт Verdana. Латиница отображается ОК.

[image]

При этом:

- в любом редакторе (Word, Photoshop) кириллица этим шрифтом отображается нормально
- в Qt Creator также шрифт отображается нормально

[image]

Еще странность - изначально Qt Creator в меню выбора шрифта для элемента управления QML Text предоставляет выбор из стандартных Arial, Verdana, Courier, Times New Roman и Tahoma

Что делать? Кто виноват?

P.S. в качестве дополнения - под линуксом все нормально.
[image]

Comment: В чём разница между Windows и Linux результатами? Я вижу `"йрсЙ"` в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бага самопоправилась.

Для этого пришлось в питоновском коде перейти с использования PySide на PyQt5

```
# было
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import *
# стало
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
```

Также в QML-файлах описания интерфейса пришлось изменить импорты:

```
//было
import QtQuick 1.0
//стало
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
```

Еще обращу внимание, что лучше всего ставить Qt Designer отдельно от Qt. С библиотекой поставлялась версия 3.1.2 программы, а с сайта можно отдельно скачать 3.2.0 и он реально лучше работает с Quick 2.x

P.S. в Qt Designer есть проблема, что он юникодовские символы, заданные своими кодами, в элементе Text не отображает:
[image]

Comment: [PySide может показывать Юникод](https://gist.github.com/zed/b0576dcd90f0edd91f30). Может быть `from __future__ import unicode_literals` не хватает в каком-нибудь модуле (Python 2)?